# React - Import a file from Node_Modules

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React but have used React Native pretty extensively.

Basically I'm struggling with something that I expect is pretty simple and common.

I want to use an NPM package bootstrap-grid-only-css (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-grid-only-css).

I have installed it and its available in the node_modules folder.  My issue is trying to import it into the app.js file.

I have tried

```
import { 'bootstrap-grid-only-css' } from "bootstrap-grid-only-css"
```

and

```
import { 'bootstrap-grid.min.css' } from "../node_modules/dist/bootstrap-grid-only-css"
```

Have also tried

const bs = require('bootstrap-grid.min.css');

none of which seem to work. all error.

Can anyone advise the correct method of import please?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes?

```js
import { bootstrap-grid-only-css } from "bootstrap-grid-only-css" 
```

Comment: @cullanrocks - yes tried that cheers - no luck!

Comment: What about without the brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are importing css file, then do not include file name after `import`

`import "../node_modules/dist/bootstrap-grid-only-css"/bootstrap-grid.min.css`

Just like:
`import 'react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css';`

Comment: thanks @Meet Zaveri . - but i get the following error - 'Module not found: You attempted to import ../node_modules/dist/bootstrap-grid-only-css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.'

Comment: Check the correct path in IDE/file folder. Then apply accordingly. If relative imports ar causing error, then try absolute imports. https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/how-to-change-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths-for-imports-32ba6cce18a5

Comment: Pleasure to provide you an assist(Not like Andy robertson :) )

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to add bootstrap to your react application. you can follow below steps according to [React Docs Adding Bootstrap](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-bootstrap)

As first step you need to add bootstrap to your project via npm install.

`npm install --save bootstrap`

you can add bootstrap version behalf of `bootstrap` in above code.

Then go to **src/index.js** file and import Bootstrap CSS and optionally Bootstrap theme CSS in the beginning adding below line in **index.js**

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Then delete all custom css write inside the **scr/App.css**

Then checkout adding bootstrap code inside the **App.js** file.It should be worked properly.

If you want go through this video [How to import bootstrap in react application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4V8CJzeD54) you will understand how does it easy.