# Import a node_module dist js file in reactjs application created using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lazy-loading, node-modules

I am new to reactjs and nodejs, I created a application using `create-react-app` and included a third party node dependency which contains a dist folder with css and js.
Since I was not able to add/refer the js and css files in `index.html` which is in public folder I tried the below methods.

1. Included the css and js files refernces in index.js inside src folder.
2. Added the dist folder inside public folder and added the reference in `index.html`.
   In both cases i think the files are included but when I create a drop down the js features are not working, but css are loading. I tried debugging the js and think the js is parsed before the component is loaded.

How can I refer a third party node module *dist js file* in a react application.

Comment: Normally you load an npm dependency by typing `npm install xxx` from the terminal when in project root. You can then see them listed in `package.json` and loaded in a folder `npm_modules`. Then you can import them with `import` statements as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463833/react-import-a-file-from-node-modules

Comment: Can you check the network tab and see if the js file is loaded ?

Comment: Yes did the same by npm install xxx and did import and require statements in index.js file. File is inside static/js/folderpath/node_modules/@xxx/js/ debugged the same , its loading while page is loading. When i try to include a component css is getting reflected. Its a dist file from thirdparty. Should i include the same in components?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you basically want to add that node module as a component in your project, So you can add that component code in your `my-project/src/component` path (not the dist files) and then import this component, where ever/however you want to use it.

Please comment below in case of further queries.

Comment: Add a node module as a component?Is there any reference?